# angularjs compile and link dom recursive manipulation

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've been working with angular for a month or so now. I'm having an issue working with dom manipulation. As an exercise, I want to create a directive that would repeat a nested object to a tree view. Please don't send me links of online example. I found plenty but most don't explain what they are doing or more importantly why the code is written that way.

I have create a plnkr as a sample code to test with located here: http://plnkr.co/edit/Zcx63dJZxQyDsjAHIALh?p=preview

Every example I found online explains that all the compile functions run before the pre or post link and the post link is where events should be registered and bound. I can also either use a link or a compile function in my directive and a compile function returns a post link. You can see in the plnkr that everything is setup this way.

I understand that the link function can take a transclude function that creates a clone of the element. This is where I'm stuck. I tried to append the clone to the element but i'm always getting my browser to freeze and being none responsive.

In the angular documentation it says:

> Note: The compile function cannot handle directives that recursively use themselves in their own templates or compile functions. Compiling these directives results in an infinite loop and a stack overflow errors. This can be avoided by manually using $compile in the postLink function to imperatively compile a directive's template instead of relying on automatic template compilation via template or templateUrl declaration or manual compilation inside the compile function

but there's no example on what's the process of manipulating the dom. How do we handle recursion in the link function using compile? In some examples they clear the element html and then append the clone. Why? How can I recursively build and append templates? Is it better to have the element transcluded into a template or is it better to have my template in the directive and then clone it?

I hope you can help me as I can't find anything that would go in details of the compile function and the steps that are needed when it comes to recursive dom manipulation. If you want to help please provide an explanation of each line of the code.

Thank you for the help,

Answer (score 1):

Hi I fixed the plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/gbeljxdShUazBJux7hXB

The biggest problem I saw was that your recursion never ended which is why there was a stack overflow.

let me know if you have any questions.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the help. The solution you added is one of the actual code I found online with another plnkr post somewhere. What I was really looking for is: What stopped the recursion? is it the call to tElem.contents().remove()? another thing what does this line do: compiledContents = $compile(contents, transclude)? where is the doc for the $compile service and what parameters it takes and what does it return? at the end, how is that return value used in the last call to clone the element? how come the link func didn't have a transclude param? how did you get that?

Comment: The recursion stops when the code in the template: ng-repeat="node in nodes.children" finishes.  In your plunkr you kept appending your template over and over and there was no end

Comment: At least give the person a positive useful mark for going to the effort of answering your question.